# Can't render parent props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, openweathermap

I'm making a React app using openweathermap API. Right now I receive the list of weather data. I'm trying to highlight the weather if I click it.

To make this happen, I wrote  on App.js to pass a prop to WeatherDetail.js, but so far seems like WeatherDetail.js doesn't recognize props from its parent.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    state = { forecasts: [], selectedWeather: null }

    getWeather = async city => {
        const response = await weather.get('/forecast', {
            params: {
                q: city
            }
        });
            this.setState ({
                forecasts: response.data.list,
                city: response.data.city.name,
                selectedWeather: response.data.list[0]
            })            
        }
    }

    onWeatherSelectFunction = (item) => {
        this.setState({ selectedWeather: item });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form loadWeather={this.getWeather} />
                <WeatherDetail itemToChild={this.state.selectedWeather} />
                <WeatherList                     
                    onWeatherSelect={this.onWeatherSelectFunction}
                    weathers={this.state.forecasts}
                    city={this.state.city}
                />
            </div>
        );        
    }
}

export default App;
```

```
const WeatherDetail = ({forecasts, itemToChild}, props) => {
    const weather = props.itemToChild;
    if(!weather) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <div>{weather.humidity}</div> <-- This doesn't appear on screen
    );
}
```

```
const WeatherItem = ({item, onWeatherSelectFromList, humidity, city, temp }) => {

        return (
            <div>                
                <div onClick={() => onWeatherSelectFromList(item)} >
                        {city}<br /> <-- Appears on screen
                        {humidity}<br /> <-- Appears on screen
                </div>
            </div>
        );
};
```

```
const WeatherList = ({weathers, onWeatherSelect, city}) => {           
        const renderedList = weathers.map((item) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <WeatherItem
                        city={city}
                        temp={item.main.temp}
                        humidity={item.main.humidity}
                        temperature={item.weather.icon}
                        onWeatherSelectFromList={onWeatherSelect}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        });        
        return (
            <div className="flex">
                {renderedList}
            </div>
        );
}
```

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    state = { term: '' };

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.loadWeather(this.state.term);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                        <input   
                        ref="textInput"
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.state.term} 
                        onChange={event => this.setState({term: event.target.value})}
                        />
                        <button>Get Weather</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How do I connect App.js and WeatherDetail.js using props?

Answer (score 1):

In your **App.js** file you are passing only one props called **itemToChild**

```
<WeatherDetail itemToChild={this.state.selectedWeather} />
```

In your WeatherDetail file from where you're getting **forecasts**? do you get forecasts from redux store?

```
const WeatherDetail = ({forecasts, itemToChild}, props) => {
  const weather = props.itemToChild;
  if(!weather) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return <div>{weather.humidity}</div> <-- This doesn't appear on screen
  );
}
```

change your code with this.

```
const WeatherDetail = (props) => {
  console.log("props.itemToChild", props.itemToChild) // check this console that do you get data as you want.
  const weather = props.itemToChild;
  if(!weather) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return <div>{weather.humidity}</div> <-- This doesn't appear on screen
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried the console log and it said 'undefined'. I'm not using Redux, I put forecasts randomly hoping to make things work... I also consoled log 'selectedWeather'. Object appeared in console for the first click, but after second click it starts to say 'undefined'..

Answer (score 0):

You have already destructured the props so there is no need to mention `props` in WeatherDetail component
and also there is an extra parenthesis after the return statement you should remove that also...

**Old:**

```
const WeatherDetail = ({forecasts, itemToChild}, props) => {
    const weather = props.itemToChild;
    if(!weather) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <div>{weather.humidity}</div> <-- This doesn't appear on screen
    );
}
```

**New:**

```
const WeatherDetail = ({ forecasts, itemToChild }) => {
  const weather = itemToChild;
  if (!weather) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return <div>{weather.humidity}</div>;
};
```

Comment: try to log the `this.state.selectedWeather` in App.js .. Maybe from App.js it can't find the value you are passing to WeatherDetail component...let me know what output it shows after you log the state

Comment: When I log 'this.state.selectedWeather', an Object appeared on the first click, but after second click it turned to 'undefined'.